# what is the role of elected master elasticsearch (ELK Stack)

Tags: elasticsearch

1. What is the main purpose of elected master in ELK. If elected master to have only node.master enabled, node.data disabled and not allowed to take any searching and indexing requests.
2. I have 3 node cluster in which 1 is elected master. If I have kibana as front end UI for querying data and logstash sending data to the cluster for indexing (for realtime log analysis) , Is it a good idea to send searching/indexing requests to other 2 master nodes apart from elected master. or select 1 node for searching or another node for indexing leaving elected master untouched. Please advice.

Please suggest me what would be the best plan

Plan A

[image]

or

Plan B

[image]

or Plan C

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elected master is a node elected between data nodes and the function of master is to maintain cluster state. Cluster state is the data which Has information on the entire cluster . What nodes are present , what indices are present and which shards are in which nodes etc are stored in cluster state , though only master is allowed to make any changes to cluster state , every node will have a copy of it. This removes single dependency of master and make it possible for any node to become master. 
Now as the function of master is thin , it doesn't make sense to have dedicated masters until and unless you have crazy number of nodes.

Comment: Hi Vineet, Sorry I have just added one more diagram to the question i.e  Plan C which contains all the nodes should have primaries allocated. So, As per the answer should i consider Plan C as i am currently running on 3 nodes now?

Comment: Okay looks cool for me. One quick question regarding searching of data. Can i have searching requests going to one node or three nodes? I meant adding lb to balance requests between kibana and  ES

Comment: "it doesn't make sense to have dedicated masters until and unless you have crazy number of nodes" this is not entirely true. If your data nodes are heavily loaded, you don't want this heavy load to interfere with the administrative tasks a master node is performing. And IT IS recommended to balance the search requests between all nodes, is not a matter of preference, it's a strong recommendation!

Comment: @AndreiStefan - I agree. But then putting a single master node as dedicated master will bring in single point of failure. So its recommended to have atelast 3 dedicated master , if you plan for dedicated master.

Comment: True, 3 dedicated master nodes is the best approach for any cluster where there is a danger of overloading the "master" node. And set `minimum_master_nodes: 2`